# How do I use Powershell to create an Azure Web App that runs on Linux?

Tags: powershell, azure

In the Azure Portal I'm able to specify the host operating system when creating a Web App. How can I achieve the same via Powershell? I' looked into the docs of the [New-AzureRmWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/new-azurermwebapp?view=azurermps-6.4.0) and [New-AzureRmAppServicePlan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/new-azurermappserviceplan?view=azurermps-6.4.0) cmdlets but wasn't able to find any references on how to pass the OS as parameter. I also tried via the Azure CLI 2.0 on Ubuntu without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the command below, it works fine on my side, it creates a Linux Service Plan and a Linux web app in it.

```
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Location <Location> -ResourceType microsoft.web/serverfarms -ResourceName <YourPlanName> -kind linux -Properties @{reserved="true"} -Sku @{name="S1";tier="Standard"; size="S1"; family="S"; capacity="1"} -Force
New-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <YourAppName> -AppServicePlan <YourPlanName>
```

[image]

Check it in the Azure Resource Explorer.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: At first when I tried this I got the following error: https://pastebin.com/3ffdbxXU. But then when I tried another region (Central US) it worked just fine. It's just weird that there's no way to create a Linux App Service Plan via the New-AzureRmAppServicePlan cmdlet. Thank you!