# How to create a Linux AppService Plan with New-AzAppServicePlan?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-cli

What is the equivalient of this code using `New-AzAppServicePlan`?

```
    az appservice plan create --resource-group $ServerFarmResourceGroupName `
        --name $AppServicePlanName `
        --is-linux `
        --location $ResourceGroupLocation `
        --sku $AppServicePlanTier `
        --number-of-workers $NumberOfWorkers
```

Is there really no way to create an App Service Plan using Az Powershell? Why can it only be done via Azure CLI or ARM?

I only found this answer, which basically uses ARM directly: [How do I use Powershell to create an Azure Web App that runs on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51353318/how-do-i-use-powershell-to-create-an-azure-web-app-that-runs-on-linux)

Comment: You're right ... seems that is does not support linux: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/7096

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally used my script to create a ConsumptionPlan (Y1) through PowerShell and AzureCLI because I don't like when Azure put a generated name when creating a ConsumptionPlan.

Please find my solution to create a Linux App Service Plan (B1) using **New-AzResource**:

```
$fullObject = @{
   location = "West Europe"
   sku = @{
        name = "B1"
        tier = "Basic"
   }
   kind = "linux"
   properties = @{
        reserved = $true
   }
}

$resourceGroupName = "rg-AppServicePlanLinux"
$serverFarmName = "aspl-test"

Write-Host "Step 1: CREATING APP SERVICE PLAN B1:Basic named [$serverFarmName]"
# Create a server farm which will host the function app in the resource group specified
New-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms" -Name $serverFarmName -IsFullObject -PropertyObject $fullObject -Force
```

So I used the ARM template to understand which information you need to provide on the **-PropertyObject** parameter

It also now seems possible to do an App Service Plan Linux with **New-AzAppServicePlan** command since Az PowerShell 4.3.0 (June 2020) with the parameter **-Linux**

> Az.Websites
>
> Added safeguard to delete created webapp if restore failed in 'Restore-AzDeletedWebApp'
>
> Added 'SourceWebApp.Location' for 'New-AzWebApp' and 'New-AzWebAppSlot'
>
> Fixed bug that prevented changing Container settings in 'Set-AzWebApp' and 'Set-AzWebAppSlot'
>
> Fixed bug to get SiteConfig when -Name is not given for Get-AzWebApp
>
> **Added a support to create ASP for Linux Apps**
>
> Added exceptions for clone across resource groups

Release Note: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/release-notes-azureps?view=azps-5.6.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-4.3.0#azwebsites-7

New-AzAppServicePlan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azappserviceplan?view=azps-5.6.0

If you get "The Service is unavailable" after deploying your new Function app (Consumption Plan) with Azure CLI, please make sure the following statement from Microsoft:
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Creating-Function-Apps-in-an-existing-Resource-Group
I waste the whole day because I got another Function App (Premium Plan) in the same resource group I used to deploy the Consumption one.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues about this, suppose for now this is not supported for `New-AzureRmAppServicePlan`, however you could use `New-AzureRmResource` to create a linux plan. You could try the below command.

```
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <>group name  -Location "Central US" -ResourceType microsoft.web/serverfarms -ResourceName <plan name>  -kind linux -Properties @{reserved="true"} -Sku @{name="S1";tier="Standard"; size="S1"; family="S"; capacity="1"} -Force
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is also the solution in the answer I linked to in my question... I was hoping for a different solution.

Comment: Check this [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/7096#issuecomment-507961265), suppose this  feature will come online after a while.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it with the Az module ie New-AzResource and it worked fine for me. There are a number of subtle things ones needs to watch though.

@GeorgeChen, how does one enable container support?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Adding `-Linux` as a parameter to my command

```
New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME -Name $APP_SERVICE_PLAN_NAME -Location $RESOURCE_LOCATION -Linux -Tier $APP_SERVICE_PLAN_TIER -NumberofWorkers $APP_SERVICE_PLAN_WORKERS -WorkerSize $APP_SERVICE_PLAN_WORKER_SIZE
```

Example:

```
New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName 'MyResourceGroup' -Name 'MyServicePlan' -Location 'northeurope' -Linux -Tier 'PremiumV2' -NumberofWorkers 2 -WorkerSize Medium
```